# VisualStudioでsvmlightを使いたいのですがエラーが発生してしまいます。

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, 機械学習

私はVisualStudio2015でsvmlightを使い、プログラムを書いています。

ここにあるソースを用いました。
https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG
しかしコンパイルしようとしてもsvmlight.hから以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

---

```
エラー (アクティブ)     "WORD" があいまいです  Get_Car_Information c:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\svmlight\svmlight.h    137 
エラー C2872   'WORD': あいまいなシンボルです。    Get_Car_Information c:\users\kanazashi\documents\get_car_information\get_car_information\svmlight\svmlight.h    137 
エラー C2440   '=': 'svmlight::WORD' から 'WORD' に変換できません。   Get_Car_Information c:\users\kanazashi\documents\get_car_information\get_car_information\svmlight\svmlight.h    140 
エラー C2228   '.weight' の左側はクラス、構造体、共用体でなければなりません Get_Car_Information c:\users\kanazashi\documents\get_car_information\get_car_information\svmlight\svmlight.h    141 
エラー C2228   '.wnum' の左側はクラス、構造体、共用体でなければなりません   Get_Car_Information c:\users\kanazashi\documents\get_car_information\get_car_information\svmlight\svmlight.h    141
```

---

このエラーの解決方法が分かりません。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765698/errors-in-using-svmlight-on-visual-studio
ここにある回答を読み、解決を試みました。
具体的には、WORDのあいまいさを回避するため、svmlight::wordと書き直しました。
しかし、回答者の言う「いくらかのリンクのエラー」が発生してしまい、その解決法もわかりません。
そのエラーも以下に記載します。

---

```
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル free_example が関数 "private: virtual __cdecl SVMlight::~SVMlight(void)" (??1SVMlight@@EEAA@XZ) で参照されました。   Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル free_model が関数 "private: virtual __cdecl SVMlight::~SVMlight(void)" (??1SVMlight@@EEAA@XZ) で参照されました。 Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル read_documents が関数 "public: void __cdecl SVMlight::read_problem(char *)" (?read_problem@SVMlight@@QEAAXPEAD@Z) で参照されました。 Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル my_malloc が関数 "private: __cdecl SVMlight::SVMlight(void)" (??0SVMlight@@AEAA@XZ) で参照されました。   Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル svm_learn_regression が関数 "public: void __cdecl SVMlight::train(void)" (?train@SVMlight@@QEAAXXZ) で参照されました。   Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル kernel_cache_cleanup が関数 "private: virtual __cdecl SVMlight::~SVMlight(void)" (??1SVMlight@@EEAA@XZ) で参照されました。   Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2019 未解決の外部シンボル write_model が関数 "public: void __cdecl SVMlight::saveModelToFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?saveModelToFile@SVMlight@@QEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) で参照されました。   Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK2001 外部シンボル "verbosity" は未解決です。  Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\Get_Car_Information\learnSVM.obj   1   
エラー LNK1120 8 件の未解決の外部参照    Get_Car_Information C:\Users\Kanazashi\Documents\Get_Car_Information\x64\Debug\Get_Car_Information.exe  1
```

---

完全に私の知識不足ですが、どなたか解決方法を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: svmlightは別途svmlight/にダウンロードしておき、一緒にコンパイルするといったことが trainHOG のチュートリアルに書かれていますが、このあたりの作業は行っていますか？ https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial#preparations

Comment: Visual Studioで動かしたいため、少しコンパイルの手順などが変わってきてしまっています。一応ディレクトリはチュートリアルの指示通りにしましたが…。

Comment: svmlightのコードをディレクトリに展開するだけではなく、プロジェクトに追加し、一緒にコンパイルしなければなりません。もしくは提示された質問の回答にあるように、別途.lib形式としてコンパイルしておいてリンクします。未解決の外部参照というのは宣言だけで定義（実装）が見つからないということですから、これらの作業を行っていないのではないでしょうか？（具体的な操作方法の説明に自信がないので、とりあえずコメントにて）